# R - dividing a column into two related ones

Tags: r

im looking for a solution to my problem.  The table looks something like this.

[]  text
1   alpha
2   1
3   2
4   beta
5   3
6   4
7   gamma
8   5
9   6
10  7

The numbers correspond to the letter above them.

I have ealready created a new column with only the Greek letters and NA. What I want to do now is: loop through the letters column and assign every letter to its corresponding number, so that at the end it looks like this:

[]  text    letters
1   alpha   alpha
2   1   alpha
3   2   alpha
4   beta    beta
5   3   beta
6   4   beta
7   gamma   gamma
8   5   gamma
9   6   gamma
10  7   Gamma

df$letters[grepl("[:lower:]",df$text)] <- df$text[grepl("[:lower:]",df$text)]
is how I created the second column which leaves me with only the letters and NA values for rows with numbers. Now I want to replace the NA with letter from above

I hope the issue is clear. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please could you include the code that you have written so far and indicate where your problem is?

Comment: i updated the question. Sorry, I'm new to Stackoverflow. I hope you will see that